# Laravel: how after creating stay at the page to create one more item

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

For example: I'm on Create Company Page. I need: when the user clicks “create” will be show modal window “Company successfully created. Do you want create one?” and buttons “No, thanks”, “Yes”
If the user clicks “No, thanks” he will be return on the Page Companies (index page, there are all Conpanies shown).
If the user clicks “Yes” he will be stay on current page for create new Company.

My method to store Company:

```
public function store(StoreCompanyRequest $request)
{
   $company = Company::create($request->all());

   return redirect()->route('admin.companies.index');
}
```

How to realize js modal window in `create.blade.php` and what to return in store method (prevent redirect or no)?

Answer (score 0):

Front end interaction like this is usually done using Javascript. You would capture the submit button click, then show a modal and post to the server to save your new customer.